# Label moves to the left when table cell was reused

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a table with a custom table cell in it. That's how it looks at startup:

[image]

Now, when I scroll so that the cell disappears and I let go, the cell comes back to the screen, but it now looks like this:

[image]

The table data is fetched using `NSFetchedResultsController`. I've done exactly this multiple times before, this never happened.

My `cellForRowAt`method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bitCell", for: indexPath) as! BitCell
        let entry = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

        cell.configure(cellWithText: entry.text!)
        return cell
    }
```

My custom `BitCell` class

```
class BitCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bitTextLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        //selectionStyle = .none
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    func configure(cellWithText text: String) {
        //bitTextLabel.text = text
    }

}
```

And my constraints for the label:
[image]

Let me know, if you need anything more (I will edit the question with additional information)

Thanks!

Comment: Is the superview for the label just the content view of the cell?

Comment: Taking a look back at your constraints, it seems that you are using a smaller view to encapsulate the two labels (since your bottom space and top space constraints both have constants of zero). Is this the case?

Comment: Did you give constraints to the `UITableView` and each and every content of `prototype-cell` ????

Comment: Yes, it is. I tried that as a solution, but it didnt change anything. Before, the superview was the cell and it behaved the same.

Comment: Yes, I did @the_dahiya_boy

Comment: **Try this :** Add a `UIView` in cell with constraints top,botton, trailing, leading = 0, and in this `UIVIew` add label.

Comment: That's what I tried :D. That's the case right now, in fact. It didn't change anything, unfortunately

Comment: Do you see any constraint errors in your console output when you scroll?

Comment: No, there are no errors. Strangely, I just deleted the Label and created a new one. I set the exact same constraints etc. but now i works perfectly fine. But I don't think that's a solution to that problem. Something is causing sometimes problems, I have no idea what, though.

Comment: Try to call [self setNeedLayouts] and [self setLayoutIfNeed] on your `configure(cellWithText:)` method.

Comment: Good idea, I didn't think of that. I added it, i seems to work. But I don't know if it solves the problem as I somehow avoided it by recreating the label. To test this properly I would have to know the cause of the problem to reproduce it.